# Unexpected numpy interpolation behavior for x array spanning negative to positive (ordered as increasing)

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Using `np.interp(query, x, y)` produces the same results as I calculate in Excel sometimes. Here is a case where `np.interp()` and Excel agree:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [-9.210,-6.908,-4.605,-2.303,0.000,2.303],
     'y': [-1.867,-1.867,-2.027,-3.667,-7.850,-21.112]}
)

val = -7.313

test1 = np.interp(val, df['x'], df['y'])
```

And `print(test1)` yields `-1.867`. This is exactly as I calculate in Excel and it looks right (our query value is between the yellow values): 
[image]

However, `test2 = np.interp(val, df['y'], df['x'])` yields `2.303`. In Excel, I calculate `-0.2956`, which looks right because our query value is between the yellow values.
[image]

Is there some kind of weird behavior in numpy where it gets confused going from negative to zero to positive when trying to interpolate? I have tried this with a much more descritized dataframe (50 rows instead of these 6), and the values are always in increasing order, and I get the same issue.

Comment: scipy interpolate performs as expected: `f = interpolate.interp1d(df['y'], df['x'])` ... `test2 = f(val)` returns -0.2956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the predictor column must be in increasing order. (Note: -21 is less than -1.8 on the number line, as is -1 less than 1.) Use sort_values to sort the data frame in ascending order by column y, and then the output matches your Excel output.

```
df1=df.sort_values(by="y")

test3= np.interp(val, df1["y"], df1["x"])

print(test3)

-0.29565168539325837
```